# +i returns lvalue?

Tags: c

Below code gives error on compilation in a C compiler

```
++(-i);
error: lvalue required as increment operand
```

It means that -i returns rvalue.

while code

```
++(+i);
```

don't give any error . Why so? [this link](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/artaddi.htm) says that +i don't result in lvalue.

Comment: Well, I can see how that happened.  You'll need to file a bug with your compiler vendor.  Don't expect a quick response.

Comment: Yes this is definitively a bug in your compiler. For our curiosity, which one is it?

Comment: i m working with code block IDE

Comment: Probably gcc/mingw then. Which operating system are you on? And did you by change configure Code Blocks to use a different compiler?

Comment: i m on windows 7 . and i didn't change compiler

Comment: I see this behavior on two compilers I have installed - VC6 and Digital Mars; none of the newer VC compilers have it. Even an ancient GCC (3.4.5) gives an error on ++(+i), so I doubt Code::Blocks is using MinGW. I suspect that your Code::Blocks IDE is using VC6 somehow. Can you give the *exact* error message (using copy/paste) when `++(-i)` is used - that may help us determine which compiler is being used (I'm sure there's a better way, but I'm not familiar enough with Code::Blocks to say how).

Comment: @MichaelBurr.. i think this link will be enough http://ideone.com/EgeH1

Comment: @pawan: that's interesting.  the gcc 4.3.4 compiler used on ideone.com doesn't complain about `++(+i)`, but the gcc 3.4.5 and gcc 4.7.0 compilers I have on hand both do.  Looks like gcc regressed on this bug at some point, then fixed it.  Either that or ideone.com is passing some mysterious option that enables this behavior. You may want to look into updating the compiler you have installed inside the Code::Blocks IDE - I'm not sure if it would be worth it just for this particular odd-ball bug, but there are likely other fixes and features (C++11 support!) that you'd probably get.

Comment: @MichaelBurr, GCC 4.4.7 doesn't complain about `++(+i)`, but 4.5.3, 4.6.3 and 4.7.1 all do. So the regression was fixed for version 4.5, it seems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a glitch in your compiler. In C language all lvalues in expressions are converted to rvalues even before any operators are applied, with the exception of operands of `sizeof`, `&`, `++`, `--` and left-hand sides of `.` and assignment (see 6.3.2/2)

In other words, in C language `+i` must produce an rvalue not because unary `+` supposedly produces an rvalue, but rather because `i` is converted to rvalue *before* that unary `+` even gets a chance to do its thing.

For example, for an `int i` variable that holds value `42`, expression `+i` is fully equivalent to expression `+42`. The lvalueness of `i` is lost and it gets turned into `42` *before* the semantics of unary `+` comes into play.

Needless to say, in this case there's no chance the result of unary `+` can be an lvalue.

Answer (score 0):

From the C99 standard (*6.5.3.3 Unary arithmetic operators*):

> 2 The result of the unary + operator is the value of its (promoted) operand. The integer promotions are performed on the operand, and the result has the promoted type.
>
> 3 The result of the unary - operator is the negative of its (promoted) operand. The integer promotions are performed on the operand, and the result has the promoted type.

In *this particular context*, there's no code which would use the promoted value `+i`, thus I believe that your compiler assumes it being equivalent to `i`, and for this reason treats it a lvalue. Or maybe simply it doesn't implement unary `+` at all. Anyway, that's not a thing you should be doing at all, and other compilers will simply forbid it.

`-i` performs an actual operation so its result is a temporary. Thus, you can't increment it because it's not the variable anymore.

And the standard makes that clear in *6.3.2.1 Other operands / Lvalues, arrays, and function designators*:

> 2 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the unary & operator, the ++ operator, the -- operator, or the left operand of the . operator or an assignment operator, an lvalue that does not have array type is converted to the value stored in the designated object (and is no longer an lvalue). […]

Comment: `+i` does do something; it promotes it's operand. You've quoted the right part of the standard but have come to the wrong conclusion. `i` is not equivalent to `+i`.

Comment: Both of these result in a _value_, as you quoted, not an _lvalue_ (check the wording on the `*` operator just a few paragraphs above).

Comment: @CharlesBailey: erm, but promote to *what* since there's no other context here?

Comment: @MichałGórny "integer promotions", which are probably defined somewhere else entirely in the standard. It refers to rule like `someShort + someInt` converting the short to an integer first.

Comment: @delnan: But assuming that `i` is an *int*, I don't see why it would be promoted to anything else.

Comment: @MichałGórny I'm shaky on the exact rules, but I also assume it wouldn't do anything. But for many other types, it does something, and thus *in general* `(+something)` is something else.

Comment: @delnan: And I have explicitly written that it doesn't do anything *in this context*. Not in general, where the general case is explained within the quotation itself.

Comment: The fact that `+i` is not an lvalue is in C99 6.3.2.1/2 "Lvalues, arrays and function designators": " Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the unary `&` operator,the `++` operator,the `--` operator, or the left operand of the `.` operator or an assignment operator, an lvalue that does not have array type is converted to the value stored in the designated object **(and is no longer an lvalue)**" (emphasis added).

Comment: Yeah, I'm not saying it is currently wrong (no downvote either). It could be more explicit that what the compiler is doing is wrong though.

Comment: @MichałGórny: It doesn't matter that the type to which it is promoted is the same as the type of the operand, it's the fact the the result of the operation is now a _value_ logically distinct from the original lvalue operand `i`.

Comment: Well, thanks for clarifying that for me. I've also updated the answer, and hope no one will now get confused reading it.